# Firestore OncompleteListener

Tags: android, collections, listener, google-cloud-firestore, document

I want to see what is the error in this code for the executiom, when i compile it it just returns the values of log 1,3,2 , and i wanto log 2 to be before the 3

```
Log.d("1", "antes de validar");
    DocumentReference docRef = db.getDb().collection("Usuarios").document(Correo);
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            Log.d("2", "validar");
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(true);
                    return;
                } else {
                    setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(false);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(contextoRegistro, "ERROR al Realizar la validacion de Correo"+ task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(false);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    Log.d("3", "despues de validar");
    return BanderaValidarCorreoDB;
}
```

This is how it shows

```
07-08 13:47:56.968 6027-6027/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen D/1: antes de 
 validar
07-08 13:47:56.980 6027-6027/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen D/3: despues de validar
07-08 13:47:57.071 6027-6052/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 13:47:57.071 6027-6052/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe2b2a700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 13:47:57.149 6027-6052/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 13:47:57.149 6027-6052/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe2cf7540, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 13:47:57.177 6027-6052/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen V/RenderScript: 0xeff9b600 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
07-08 13:47:58.483 6027-6027/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen D/2: validar
07-08 13:52:35.654 6027-6068/felipe.monumentosfinalcertamen I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Comment: put a breakpoint at your second log and see from there what is happening and if the code is beign executed

Comment: I wrote an answer below, but will also close as a duplicate. Let me know if the answer doesn't make sense though.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from Cloud Firestore asynchronously. By the time your `return BanderaValidarCorreoDB`, the data hasn't loaded yet. There is no way to make the return statement wait for the data to be loaded. That is by design, and I highly recommend embracing programming against asynchronous APIs sooner rather than later.

The solution can be one of two things:

1. Move the code that needs the data *into* `onComplete`.
2. Pass your own callback interface into your helper function that loads the data.

Moving the code that needs the data into `onComplete` is the simplest. It's similar to how you already call `setBanderaValidarCorreoDB`, but then also call the code that needs the value of `BanderaValidarCorreoDB`:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(true);
        } else {
            setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(false);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(contextoRegistro, "ERROR al Realizar la validacion de Correo"+ task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(false);
    }
    doSomethingWithBanderaValidarCorreoDB(BanderaValidarCorreoDB);
}
```

This is simple, but reduces the reuse of you helper function a bit. So you can also define your own interface, and pass that into your helper function to call back. Code may be simpler to follow than words here, so:

```
public interface BanderaValidarCorreoDBCallback {
  void onCallback(boolean value);
}
void getBanderaValidarCorreoDB(BanderaValidarCorreoDBCallback callback)
    DocumentReference docRef = db.getDb().collection("Usuarios").document(Correo);
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(true);
                    return;
                } else {
                    setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(false);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(contextoRegistro, "ERROR al Realizar la validacion de Correo"+ task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setBanderaValidarCorreoDB(false);
                return;
            }
            callback(BanderaValidarCorreoDB);
        }
    });
}
```

And then you invoke it as:

```
getBanderaValidarCorreoDB(new BanderaValidarCorreoDBCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onCallback(boolean value) {
    System.out.println("Loaded "+value)
  }
});
```

This is an extremely common source of confusion for developers new to asynchronous programming. So I also recommend you check out some of these other sources:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705) (which also shows that waiting sometimes is possible, but not reliably on Android).
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Android: Get a Pojo List from Firebase during the first initialization from the Service Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656763/android-get-a-pojo-list-from-firebase-during-the-first-initialization-from-the/50658151#50658151)
- Doug's great [blog post on asynchronous APIs](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93).

While many of these are for the Firebase realtime database, the problem and solution are the same across all technologies.