# Firestore - Return a value from a Document Snapshot Java/Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I need to return the value that is retrieved from the document snapshot. I can see the correct value in the LOG but since it is out of scope, and only in onComplete, I cannot access it.
Can you please help?

```
public String getCoEmail() {
    coUserReference = db.collection("users").document(email);
  
    coUserReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
               if (document.exists()) {
                  String coEmail = document.getString("coEmail");
                  Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getString("coEmail"));
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    return coEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return it after **Log.d**:

```java
Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getString("coEmail"));
return document.getString("coEmail");
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously, and your main code continues while this is going on. This means that your `return coEmail` now runs before the `coEmail = document.getString("coEmail")`, even if you were to fix the scoping problem.

The solution is to make sure all code that needs the data is inside the `onComplete` method, or called from there. See for a longer example of this: [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413), or [Firestore OncompleteListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234670/firestore-oncompletelistener/51236617#51236617)